# To check the continuity of $f$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $f:(C^1[a,b],\|.\|_{\infty})\to \mathbb K$  and $c\in (a,b)$ be such that $f(x)=x^{'}(c)$ for all $x\in C^1[a,b]$. Then is $f$ a continuous linear functional?

I chose $a=0,b=1$ and $c=1$, then it can be easily shown that $f$ is not continuous. But this doesn't serve my purpose. Because $c$ should come from $(a,b)$. Please suggest.

Comment: did you mean $c\in[a,b]$? Because as it is written now $c\neq 1$ as it is not included.

Comment: No $c$ must come come from $(a,b)$, that is why my work did not materialise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of continuity of $f$ can be sensed intuitively by considering that  if real functions  $g, h$ are close, it tells us nothing about the closeness of $g'$ and $h'.$ Consider the case $h=0.$

For example, let $$g_n(t)= n^{-1}\sin [ n^2 (t-c)]$$ for $t\in [0,1]$ and $c\in (0,1)$ and $n\in N.$ We have $\|g_n\|_{\infty}\leq 1/n$ but $g'_n(c)=n.$ So the sequence $(g_n)_{n\in N}$ converges in the $\sup$ norm to the constant function $0,$ but $(g'_n(c))_{n\in N}$ is not even a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question depends on the norm you're equipping $C^1[a,b]$ with.

If you define for a continuously differentiable function $x:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb C$

$$\|x\|_{C^1}=\|x\|_\infty + \|x'\|_\infty=\sup_{t\in [a,b]}|x(t)|+\sup_{t \in [a,b]}|x'(t)|,$$

then you need to check if there is some constant $M$ such that for all continuous functions $x$ we have

$$|f(x)| \leq M \| x\|_{C^1}.$$

**Edit:** As we're considering $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ as a norm, it can be shown that $f$ is not continuous.

If $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $c=1$, consider $x_n(t)= t^n$. Then $x'(t) = n(t)^{n-1}$.

What does this mean for $|f(x_n)|$? What's $\|x_n\|_\infty$?

How can you generalize this example to the general case for $c$ and $[a,b]$?

Comment: $\|.\|_{\infty}$ is given in $C^1[a,b]$

Comment: You should add that to your question.

Comment: Yes I am adding

Comment: $|f(x_ n)|=n$ but $\|x_n\|_{\infty}=(2-c)^n$. How to show the discontinuity of $f$?

Comment: @Anupam: Obviously, I did a mistake in renormalizing $x$ - I'd like to have $f(x_n)=n$, but $\|x_n\|_\infty=1$. I will need to fix that.